# Output require() construct with AMD generation

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

I currently have a set of RequireJs modules defined as:

```
require(['dep1', 'dep2'], function(dep2, dep2) {
    ...
});
```

I'm looking to convert these into TypeScript modules, however the AMD generation outputs them with the `define()` construct:

```
define(['dep1', 'dep2'], function(dep2, dep2) {
    ...
});
```

I can see how they would essentially be equivalent. However I have always worked on the following basis:

- **Define**: When you want to be able to pass the module into other modules.
- **Require**: When the module just needs to be executed

Are these assumptions redundant? Or is there a way to instruct TypeScript to output the `require()` construct for a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these assumptions redundant?

Yes. `require` should only be used when you want to *lazy load*.

> is there a way to instruct TypeScript to output the require() construct for a module

Yes. Use the requirejs definition : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/requirejs/require.d.ts and write code to call the `require` function manually.

Comment: Ok so just to clarify, there is no way to output a require() construct from a module statement, is that correct? The issue I have is that I'm defining a class inside the module to avoid polluting the global namespace. However TypeScript complains that a class must be declared inside a module or be a top level statement. Would you recommend just using "export module" and not worry that it's a define() construct that is output?

Comment: `. Would you recommend just using "export module" and not worry that it's a define() construct that is output?` 

Yes

Answer (score -1):

You can write one file manually using `require()` to load other modules or use the `data-main` property on the element loading `require.js`.